# changing zk textbox to zk int/decimal box

Tags: textbox, zk

I am using a zk textbox in a java file. When a particular condition meets, I would like to set a constraint such that the textbox accepts only "numbers or decimals". Is there a way to set a constraint or so ?

What I am looking for is something like this:

private Textbox tb = new Textbox();
if (condition) {
  tb.setConstraint("numbers only");
}

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1):

Zk provides intbox and decimalbox... u can use these components instead of those textbox

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such constraint. However, you could implement your own. There is some info about constraint in [ZK javadoc](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/)

Just curious, why not use intbox or decimalbox?

Comment: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Guide/ZUL_Components/Form_and_Inputs/Input_Controls#Constraints http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/InputElement#Constraint this is a good documentation resource for contraints

Answer (score 0):

You can find Zk with intBox which will work fine for you...

```
<intbox constraint="no negative,no empty"/>
```

For more details you can found [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Intbox)

Answer (score 0):

problem with ZK intbox is that it will skip the leading zeros , for example if v have a situation where we want to enter only number also also we have to keep leading zero for e.g 00230 , in this case intbox will discard leading zero and will return 230.